# Repeat previous index

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have an array of indicators `a`, which contains a `1` if the index of the last `0` should be replicated. Otherwise, current running index goes through:

That is,

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
i = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

with expected output

```
x = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9])
```

Again: the logic:

- arrive at index `y`
- - If `a[y] == 0`: return `i[y]`
- - If `a[y] == 1`: return `i[yy]`, where `yy` is `max yy < y: a[yy] == 0` - the "last previous index" where `a` was `0`.

`a[0] == 0`, always.

Any approach I managed to get done uses recursive methods / loops, and is not efficient at all. What's a fast way of computing `x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one vectorized way making use of `masking` and `maximum-accumulation` with `np.maximum.accumulate` -

```
i[np.maximum.accumulate(np.where(a==0, np.arange(len(a)), 0))]
```

Another way to put it would be -

```
i[np.maximum.accumulate(np.arange(len(a)) * (a==0))]
```

**Explanation**

Just to get into the details of the meat of the story here, let's break down the steps -

1] Inputs :

```
In [83]: a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
    ...: i = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    ...:
```

2] So, input `a` is :

```
In [84]: a
Out[84]: array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
```

3] Get the range array covering the length of `a` :

```
In [85]: np.arange(len(a))
Out[85]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

4] Now mask out the range array at places where a is 1, leaving us with elements corresponding to a being 0 :

```
In [86]: np.arange(len(a)) * (a==0)
Out[86]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 9, 0])
```

5] Use maximum accumulation to create the ramped structure as needed :

```
In [87]: np.maximum.accumulate(np.arange(len(a)) * (a==0))
Out[87]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9])
```

6] Finally index into i with those numbers for the desired output :

```
In [88]: i[np.maximum.accumulate(np.arange(len(a)) * (a==0))]
Out[88]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9])
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def FranciscoRodriguez(a,i): # @Francisco Rodríguez's soln
    x = []
    for idx,val in enumerate(a):
        if val==0: x.append(i[idx])
        elif val==1: x.append(x[-1])
    return x

def ThomasGuenet(a,i): # @ThomasGuenet 's soln
    x = np.zeros(len(a))
    for j, aa in enumerate(a):
        if j == 0:
            x[j] == aa
        elif aa == 1:
            x[j] = x[j-1]
        else: 
            x[j] = i[j]
    return x

def vectorizedApp1(a,i):
    return i[np.maximum.accumulate(np.where(a==0, np.arange(len(a)), 0))]

def vectorizedApp2(a,i):
    return i[np.maximum.accumulate(np.arange(len(a)) * (a==0))]
```

Timings -

Let's tile the given sample to create a bigger dataset and test out all the solutions :

```
In [78]: a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
    ...: i = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    ...: 
    ...: a = np.tile(a,100000)
    ...: i = np.tile(i,100000)
    ...: 

In [79]: %timeit FranciscoRodriguez(a,i)
    ...: %timeit ThomasGuenet(a,i)
    ...: %timeit vectorizedApp1(a,i)
    ...: %timeit vectorizedApp2(a,i)
    ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 328 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 331 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.07 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.77 ms per loop
```

Comment: `ufunc.accumulate` is extremely handy, how come I've never used that before!

Comment: Man you nailed it! I'm amazed!

Answer (score 2):

I made this approach:

```
a = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
i = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
x = []
for idx,val in enumerate(a):
    if val==0: x.append(i[idx])
    elif val==1: x.append(x[-1])
```

It is a loop that only iterates through the list once, so there is no nested loops or recursion. That way the time cost will be O(N), being N the lenght of `a`

Comment: On an array of length 10000, your code takes `0.0115` seconds, while @Divakar's tkaes `0.00036`, edging out the loop.

Answer (score 0):

To make code fast, I understood you should use the less possible possible `if`, no `for` (contains a while and try/except), preassign variables, and use numpy arrays.

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
i = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
x = np.zeros(len(a))
for j, aa in enumerate(a):
    if j == 0:
        x[j] == aa
    elif aa == 1:
        x[j] = x[j-1]
    else: 
        x[j] = i[j]
```